# numpy and statsmodels give different values when calculating correlations, How to interpret this?

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels, cross-correlation

I can't find a reason why calculating the correlation between two series A and B using `numpy.correlate` gives me different results than the ones I obtain using `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf`

Here's an example of this difference I mention:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import ccf

#Calculate correlation using numpy.correlate
def corr(x,y):
    result = numpy.correlate(x, y, mode='full')
    return result[result.size/2:]

#This are the data series I want to analyze
A = np.array([np.absolute(x) for x in np.arange(-1,1.1,0.1)])
B = np.array([x for x in np.arange(-1,1.1,0.1)])

#Using numpy i get this
plt.plot(corr(B,A))
```

[image]

```
#Using statsmodels i get this
plt.plot(ccf(B,A,unbiased=False))
```

[image]

The results seem qualitatively different, where does this difference come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf` is based on `np.correlate` but does some additional things to give the correlation in the statistical sense instead of the signal processing sense, see [cross-correlation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). What happens exactly you can see in the [source code](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html#ccf), it's very simple.

For easier reference I copied the relevant lines below:

```
def ccovf(x, y, unbiased=True, demean=True):
    n = len(x)
    if demean:
        xo = x - x.mean()
        yo = y - y.mean()
    else:
        xo = x
        yo = y
    if unbiased:
        xi = np.ones(n)
        d = np.correlate(xi, xi, 'full')
    else:
        d = n
    return (np.correlate(xo, yo, 'full') / d)[n - 1:]

def ccf(x, y, unbiased=True):
    cvf = ccovf(x, y, unbiased=unbiased, demean=True)
    return cvf / (np.std(x) * np.std(y))
```

Comment: So, the difference is that numpy doesn't normalize the covariance by the product of the standard deviations?

Comment: @EttoreMajorana, in addition, the statsmodels `ccf` substracts the means of the signals before convolution and divides the result by the length of the first signal, to arrive at the definition of correlation as in statistics.

Comment: Ohhh I see, that's just what I was looking for, thanks for your help.